# Set a value with mongoose in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a NodeJS application that communicates with an Angular app. This is a simplified version, but I'll try to explain my problem:

I will get a value from the socket connection, for example:

```
{
    Id : "1", 
    Checked : true, 
    TeamName : "Team1"
}
```

I want to update the mongoDb with mongoose so that every person with the TeamName : "Team1" gets the value Checked : true.

I have done something like this:

```
relayModel.find({TeamName : 'Team1'}, 
     {'$set' :{Checked: true}},function(err,docs){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Could not save value for relay runner: ", err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("The runners updated: ",docs)
                    }
```

But I get the error:

```
Could not save value for relay runner:  
{ [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: 
BadValue Unsupported projection option: 
$set: { Checked: true }] name: 'MongoError' }
```

Comment: You want `.update()` not `.find()`

Comment: That only updates one person. I want to update all with the same team name.

Comment: Umm. Did you look at the documentation for the "multi" option? I guess not. Which Is why I said `.update()` rather than one of the "find and update" varieties in mongoose.

Comment: Thanks! relayModel.update({TeamName : 'Team1'}, 
     {Checked: true},{multi:true},function(err,nbr, docs){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Could not save value for relay runner: ", err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("The runners updated: ",docs)
                    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really is well documented. Will go away for sure, but just to explain for you:

```
relayModel.update(
    { "TeamName": "Team1" },
    { "$set": { "Checked": true } },
    { "multi": true },
    function(err,numAffected) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log( "updated n docs: %s", numAffected );
    }
);
```

So the `.update()` with a "multi" option affects more than one document, and without it it just affects the first document matched. The returned values in the callback are the standard `err` and the "number of documents affected".

Therefore basically speaking:

1. You actually need and operator that "updates" in order to affect and update.
2. You set "multi" for more than one document and you get only the number returned as well as using the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to just affect the field that you want to change.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the updated fields in the return statement?

Comment: @petur Not for multiple documents. Per individual you can look at `.findOneAndUpdate()` and cousins which basically return the document in it's modified form. But anything over a multiple form does not. If you want to get the modified documents then you are looping updates.